# loop error in php code

Tags: php, loops

Here is my code, and it is not removing `$arr[5]` element so that I am trying to remove strings starting with `#` from my array

this is code

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        '#EXTM3U',
        '#EXTINF:177,Paul Dateh & Oren Yoel - Be More',
        'Be More.mp3',
        '#EXTINF:291,Christopher Toy - Just Because',
        'Just Because.mp3',
        '#EXTINF:238,Magnetic North - Drift Away',
        'Drift Away.mp3'
    ];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i]{0} == '#') {
            echo $arr[$i] . "\n";
            unset($arr[$i]);
        }
    }
    print_r($arr); 
?>
```

Comment: Alisherbek Rakhimov  check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more spacific :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    if (strpos($arr[$i], '#') !== false) {
     echo "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo $arr[$i]."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is always good, but an explanation helps people work out if/how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: if condition will check that your string contain # then it break out from loop otherwise it will print your desire output.There is no rocket logic in it...

Answer (score 3):

***Reason:-*** You are counting array length inside the loop and every time when any value got `unset()` from the array, length of array decreased and value of `count($array)` changed (simply decreased)

So logically your 5th and 6th element never goes through `if` condition (they never get traversed by loop because of decreasing length of the array )

***Solution 1:-*** Put count outside and it will work properly:-

```
$count = count($arr);

//loop start from 0 so use < only otherwise, sometime you will get an undefined index error

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        if ($arr[$i]{0} == '#') {
            //echo $arr[$i] . "\n";
            unset($arr[$i]);
        }
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/996494

***Solution 2:-*** That's why i prefer `foreach()` over `for()` loop

```
 foreach($arr as $key=> $ar){
        if ($ar[0] == '#') {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/996502

Answer (score 1):

Try to use additional array to push right values. You calc `count($arr);` each iteration and when you do `count($arr);` your array gets smaller and `count($arr);` returns smaller values, so last elements won't be comparing, try to use variable to calc count before loop make changes:

```
<?php 
    //...
    $start_count = count($arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $start_count; $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i]{0} == '#') {
            echo $arr[$i] . "\n";
            unset($arr[$i]);
        }
    }
```

Or remove bad element with a help of additional array, put good elements in new array and don't delete them from input array:

```
<?php

$arr = [
        '#EXTM3U',
        '#EXTINF:177,Paul Dateh & Oren Yoel - Be More',
        'Be More.mp3',
        '#EXTINF:291,Christopher Toy - Just Because',
        'Just Because.mp3',
        '#EXTINF:238,Magnetic North - Drift Away',
        'Drift Away.mp3'
    ];
    $cleared_from_mess_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i]{0} != '#') 
        {           
            array_push($cleared_from_mess_array,$arr[$i]);
        }
    }
    print_r($cleared_from_mess_array);

exit;
```